# jQuery if an element has two parent uls

Tags: jquery

How would I detect if an element had two parent uls so for example:

```
<ul>
   <li>Link
      <ul>
        <li>Link
            <ul>
                <li class="this">Link</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried:

```
if ($('.this').parent('ul').parent('ul') == true)
```

but it doesn't seem to work... Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this.

1) bottom up - starting from the element.

```
if($('.this').parents('ul').length >=2) { // >= to accomodate your markup
    return true;
}
```

2) top-down

```
if($('ul ul li.this').length > 0) {
    return true;
} // this is a better solution as it will return true for your markup as well, which has 3 ul's before the desired li
```

Performance wise, you should choose the first method, as it does not check every ul sub-tree, but only checks to see if the '.this' element has 2 or more parent ul's.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code does not work is the first parent `ul`'s immediate parent is an `li`, you would have to do this:

```
if ($('.this').parent('ul').parent('li').parent('ul') == true)
```

The jQuery [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) function accepts a selector so you could do this so assert there are two parent `ul`'s:

```
if($('.this').parents('ul').length == 2) { ... }
```

or if you want to assert at least 2 parent `ul`'s:

```
if($('.this').parents('ul').length >= 2) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('.this').parents('ul').length == 2)
```

In the code you posted above it actually has three, so I suspect you want > 1 rather than == 2.

Comment: The parent `ul`'s immediate parent is an `li` so this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parents()` which differs from `parent()` that it traverse up many levels.

```
$('.this').parents('ul').length
```

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if ($('.this').parent('ul').parent('ul').length > 0)
{
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet:

var ullength = $('.this').parents('ul').length; if (ullength == 3) { //your code }

For live demo http://jsfiddle.net/creativegala/rMk9b/2/